# How to use Linqpad to run a command with path and confirmations

Tags: cmd, linqpad

I wanted to make a quick linqpad script to run a tfpt command that undoes unmodified files.

Syntax is like this:

"c:\myProject> tfpt uu . /noget /recursive"

- So first I need to change the path to c:\myProject.
- Secondly I need to run the command "tfpt uu . /noget /recursive".
- And finally I need to confirm the undo.

Can this be done with linqpad's Util.Cmd... if so how?

Answer (score 2):

Managed to do it like so (made it a one liner).

```
Util.Cmd("echo y |tfpt uu C:\\myProject /noget /recursive");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! With the latest bits from the beta version http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx you get an utility called lprun.exe. The syntax is straighforward:

```
Usage: lprun [<options>] <scriptfile> [<script-args>]

options: (all case-insensitive)
 -format={text|html|htmlfrag|csv|csvi}   Output format. csvi=invariant CSV.
 -cxname=<connection-name>               Sets/overrides a script's connection.
 -lang=<language>                        Sets/overrides a script's language.
 -warn                                   Writes compiler warnings (to stderr).
 -optimize                               Enables compiler optimizations.
 -nunuget                                Freshens NuGet references to latest.

scriptfile: Path to script. If it's a .linq file, -lang & -cxname are optional.

script-args: Args following <script-filepath> are passed to the script itself.

Examples:
  lprun TestScript.linq
  lprun TestScript.linq > results.txt
  lprun script1.linq | lprun script2.linq
  lprun -format=csv script.linq HelloWorld
```

obviously you need to create a proper LINQPad script within the language of your choice, and yes, Util.Cmd() is the way to go

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that, I think that allows you to run a linqpad script via the console. But i'd like to run a console script via linqpad, one that requires you to first set the path and then confirm the command.